# Custom dropdown search control value accessor not getting selected when i set value in form control

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor, angular-controlvalueaccessor

This is my cutom dropdown search control value accessor . issue is when i set value in form control thats not getting selected in below control

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown-search',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown-search.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: DropdownSearchComponent,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class DropdownSearchComponent
  implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, DoCheck
{
  @Input() itemSource: any[] = [
    {
      Id: 1,
      Value: 'Tom Cruise',
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Value: 'Maria Sharapova',
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      Value: 'James Bond',
    },
  ];

  selectedValue: any;
  searchText: string = '';
  isDisabled: boolean = false;
  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  @ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autocomplete!: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

  filteredOptions$!: Observable<any[]>;
  private searchTextSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  formControl!: FormControl;

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private errorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //setting form control
    this.setFormControl();
    this.filteredOptions$ = this.searchTextSubject.pipe(
      debounceTime(100),
      distinctUntilChanged(), // Only emit if the value has changed
      map((text) => this.filterOptions(text))
    );
  }
  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this.formControl.value == null) {
      this.searchText = '';
      this.searchTextSubject.next('');
    }
  }

  setFormControl() {
    const ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
    if (ngControl instanceof FormControlName) {
      this.formControl = this.injector
        .get(FormGroupDirective)
        .getControl(ngControl);
    } else {
      this.formControl = (ngControl as FormControlDirective)
        .form as FormControl;
    }
    console.log(this.formControl);
  }
  getFormControlErrorState(control: FormControl): boolean {
    return this.errorStateMatcher.isErrorState(control, null);
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.selectedValue = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  selectOption(option: any): void {
    this.selectedValue = option;
    this.onChange(option);
    this.onTouched();
    this.autocomplete.closePanel();
  }

  onSearchTextChange(text: string): void {
    this.searchTextSubject.next(text);
  }

  filterOptions(text: string): any[] {
    if (text.trim() === '') {
      return [];
    }
    return this.itemSource.filter((item) =>
      item.Value.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
    );
  }
}
```

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
  <mat-label>Employee</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    [placeholder]="'Search and Select...'"
    [formControl]="formControl"
    [(ngModel)]="searchText"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    [class.invalid]="formControl.invalid && formControl.touched"
    (ngModelChange)="onSearchTextChange($event)"
  />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async"
      [value]="option.Value"
      (click)="selectOption(option.Id)"
    >
      {{ option.Value }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

When i set value for above cutom control thats not getting selected

```
 this.frmGroup = this.fb.group({
      name: [1, Validators.required],
      isLocked: [{ value: false }],
    });
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <app-dropdown-search formControlName="name"></app-dropdown-search>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This above is my template form field of custom form control

I setting form control value like

```
 this.frmGroup = this.fb.group({
      name: [1, Validators.required],
      isLocked: [{ value: false }],
    });
```

and also in template that i binding cutom control like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <app-dropdown-search formControlName="name"></app-dropdown-search>
    </div>
  </div>
```

i expecting cutom control must be selected with itemsource of Id is 1

Comment: Have you tried to use `trackBy` when looping trough the `mat-option`?

Comment: Yes  I tried like 
<mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn"
      [value]="option.Value"
      (click)="selectOption(option.Id)"
    >
      {{ option.Value }}
    </mat-option>
 trackByFn(index: number, item: any): number {
    return item.Id;
  }

Comment: I tried by setting value manually also like 
 this.frmGroup.get('name')?.setValue(1);

I expecting dropdown should be preselected by option of Id is 1

Comment: Why have you implemented `ngDoCheck`? This could be potentially a bottleneck.. have you tried to check if actually your abstractControl has been updated? `frmGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)`?

Comment: if i write formcontrol.valueChanges.subscribe() not satisfying that condition 
if (this.formControl.value == null) {
       this.searchText = '';
       this.searchTextSubject.next('');
     }

Comment: I think implementation of above is not properly wrking in some cases. like for edit form , and some value changes.

Comment: any flexible solution for this implemntation is apreciated